# Pandas: How to remove words in string which appear before a certain word from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a large csv file with a column containing strings. At the beginning of these strings there are a set of id numbers which appear in another column as below.

```
0      Home /buy /York /Warehouse /P000166770Ou...             P000166770
1      Home /buy /York /Plot /P000165923A plot of la...        P000165923
2      Home /buy /London /Commercial /P000165504A str...       P000165504
                         ...                        
804    Brand new apartment on the first floor, situat...       P000185616
```

I want to remove all text which appears before the ID number so here we would get:

```
0      Ou...             
1      A plot of la...        
2      A str...       
                         ...                        
804    Brand new apartment on the first floor, situat...
```

I tried something like

```
df['column_one'].str.split(df['column_two'])
```

and

```
df['column_one'].str.replace(df['column_two'],'')
```

Comment: please provide enough data to help reproduce, refer to the stackoverflow guidelines in asking questions   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Naveed I added more data.

Comment: added a solution, see if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the pattern using regex as follows:

```py
>> my_pattern = "^(Alpha|Beta|QA|Prod)\s[A-Z0-9]{7}"
>> my_series = pd.Series(['Alpha P17089OText starts here'])
>> my_series.str.replace(my_pattern, '', regex=True)
0    Text starts here
```

There is a bit of work to be done to determine the nature of your pattern. I would suggest experimenting a bit with https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

To extend your `split()` idea:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['column_one'].split(x['column_two'])[1], axis=1)

0    Text starts here
```

Comment: I solved it using something similar: `df.apply(lambda x: x['column1'].split(x['column2'])[1] if x['column2'] in x['column1'] else x['column1'], axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work using:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['column1'].split(x['column2'])[1] if x['column2'] in x['column1'] else x['column1'], axis=1)
```

This also works when the ID is not in the description. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, by applying regex to each of the row based on the code

```
import re
def ext(row):
    mch = re.findall(r"{0}(.*)".format(row['code']), row['txt'])
    if len(mch) >0:
        rtn = mch.pop()
    else:
        rtn = row['txt']
    return rtn

df['ext'] = df.apply(ext, axis=1) 
df
```

```
0                                               Ou...
1                                     A plot of la...
2                                            A str...
3    Brand new apartment on the first floor situat...
```

```
    x   txt                                                 code            ext
0   0   Home /buy /York /Warehouse / P000166770 Ou...        P000166770     Ou...
1   1   Home /buy /York /Plot /P000165923A plot of la...     P000165923     A plot of la...
2   2   Home /buy /London /Commercial /P000165504A str...    P000165504     A str...
3   804     Brand new apartment on the first floor situat... P000185616     Brand new apartment on the first floor situat...
```

Comment: Not vectorized, pandas' built in str.replace method will be faster

Comment: yes @YaakovBressler, I agree